# Universal application for android phone?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-emulator

I am developing and application it works fine on 1280*800 and 480*320 but it is not working same in other device in which it is squeezing the imageview and other widgets. please help me how can i make it as universal application for android phones.

Comment: You should read these links http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html and this http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Answer (score 0):

First your application design for one resolution .

example : suppose your mobile resolution 380*480

```
   mobile screen width:380

   textView size is 80dp   
   Assume : if width is 380dp then 100 % then

           textview width 80dp then how many %(per).

        ower answer is: 25 %
```

find screen size programmatically using belove formula

this is one example you can set dynamic height and width for the layout

```
  int width=0,height=0,left=0,right=0,top=0,bottom=0;
DisplayMetrics   displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
         int   ScreenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
          int  ScreenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
 /* <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_classRoomVideos"
            android:layout_width="95dp"
            android:layout_height="98dp"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/button_Test"
            android:layout_marginLeft="83dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/button_Test"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/classroom_lectures_videos" />*/
            width =  (int)((ScreenWidth*9.3)/100);
            height =  (int)((ScreenHeight*14.50)/100);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params_mVideo;
            params_mVideo = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)mVideoButton.getLayoutParams();
            params_mVideo.width=width;
            params_mVideo.height=height;
            params_mVideo.setMargins((int)((ScreenWidth*8.1053)/100), 0, 0, 0);
            mVideoButton.setLayoutParams(params_mVideo);
```

Comment: i am doing this in my all activity in apps but it is not working in all activity in first activity it shows some squeezing...:(

Comment: this technique is working for me ,please check it once again .

Comment: Try handling different screen ratios also.